# Boolean always turn into 'False', spontaneously

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, boolean

I'm building 'What to Do list' app,
I made my own class Bucket(String, String, bool).
3rd property bool plays a role in checking if this task has done.
I designed if bool is false, unfulfilled task get fontweight.bold and icon is shown red, and if bool is true, fulfilled task get fontweight.normal and icons is shown green.
But, as soon as bool get 'true', it turns in to 'false', spontaneously.
No other codes are designed to get bool changed.
I don't understand why :(

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('WhattoDo List')),
        floatingActionButton: IconButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              Bucket newbucket = await Navigator.of(context)
                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PopUp()));
              setState(() {
                bucketlist.add(newbucket);
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
        body: bucketlist.isEmpty
            ? Center(child: Text('List is empty'))
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: bucketlist.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  bool donecheck = bucketlist[index].isDone;
                  print(donecheck);
                  return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.teal[200],
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          bucketlist[index].whattodo,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              decoration: donecheck
                                  ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                  : TextDecoration.none),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Text(
                          bucketlist[index].deadline,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                        trailing: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text("Wanna remove?"),
                                    actions: [
                                      TextButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                        },
                                        child: Text("Cancel"),
                                      ),
                                      TextButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                          setState(() {
                                            bucketlist.removeAt(index);
                                          });
                                        },
                                        child: Text(
                                          "OK",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                        leading: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                donecheck = !donecheck;
                                print(donecheck);
                              });
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.check,
                              color: donecheck ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
                            )),
                      ));
                }));
  }
}

class Bucket {
  String whattodo;
  String deadline;
  bool isDone;

  Bucket(this.whattodo, this.deadline, this.isDone);
}

List<Bucket> bucketlist = [];

class PopUp extends StatefulWidget {
  const PopUp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PopUp> createState() => _PopUpState();
}

class _PopUpState extends State<PopUp> {
  TextEditingController textController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController textController2 = TextEditingController();
  String? errorshowingtext;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: Colors.blue[200]),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 150,
            ),
            Text(
              'Write down your task',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 25,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'What to Do', errorText: errorshowingtext),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
              controller: textController,
            ),
            TextField(
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Deadline', errorText: errorshowingtext),
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
              controller: textController2,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    String? job = textController.text;
                    String? line = textController2.text;
                    Bucket newbucket = Bucket(job, line, false);
                    if (job.isNotEmpty && line.isNotEmpty) {
                      setState(() {
                        Navigator.pop(context, newbucket);
                      });
                    } else {
                      setState(() {
                        errorshowingtext = 'contents missing';
                      });
                    }
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 150,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Cancel'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Calling ```setState()``` rebuilds the whole ```ListView``` while you need to rebuild only one list item.
Try moving your listItem into a seperate stateful widget

Comment: Thank you for your help! I followed your instruction, but it happens again. But I solved the problem, Instead of using variable 'donecheck', I used bucketlist[index].isDone. then problem solved. but i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

You already have `isDone` to check the state. Your current method doesn't update the item check status, I prefer this way

```dart
class Bucket {
  final String whattodo;
  final String deadline;
  final bool isDone;
  Bucket({
    required this.whattodo,
    required this.deadline,
    required this.isDone,
  });

  Bucket copyWith({
    String? whattodo,
    String? deadline,
    bool? isDone,
  }) {
    return Bucket(
      whattodo: whattodo ?? this.whattodo,
      deadline: deadline ?? this.deadline,
      isDone: isDone ?? this.isDone,
    );
  }
}
```

And the widget

```dart
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
 const  Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Homepage> createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('WhattoDo List')),
      floatingActionButton: IconButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            Bucket newbucket = await Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PopUp()));
            setState(() {
              bucketlist.add(newbucket);
            });
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
      body: bucketlist.isEmpty
          ? Center(child: Text('List is empty'))
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: bucketlist.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.teal[200],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        bucketlist[index].whattodo,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20,
                            decoration: bucketlist[index].isDone
                                ? TextDecoration.lineThrough
                                : TextDecoration.none),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        bucketlist[index].deadline,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  title: Text("Wanna remove?"),
                                  actions: [
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                      child: Text("Cancel"),
                                    ),
                                    TextButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                        setState(() {
                                          bucketlist.removeAt(index);
                                        });
                                      },
                                      child: Text(
                                        "OK",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete)),
                      leading: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              bucketlist[index] = bucketlist[index]
                                  .copyWith(isDone: !bucketlist[index].isDone);
                            });
                          },
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.check,
                            color: bucketlist[index].isDone
                                ? Colors.green
                                : Colors.red,
                          )),
                    ));
              },
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to update the list todo value. not the Widget of Listile value.

change this

```
leading: IconButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        // your code:  donecheck = !donecheck;
        bucketlist[index].isDone = !donecheck;  // change to this
        print(donecheck);
      });
    },
```